# Unity import text or json

Tags: c#, unity, text

Can't seem to find a definitive way to import text to C# in Unity3d. I'm looking to import either a lot of different text files or one large json file to represent all the text in the game.

Thanks for your help

Comment: Are you talking about loading a text file that you have in Unity when you build the game, or are you talking about loading an external file on the user's machine? If the latter, then what platform are you talking about?

Comment: simply importing text into unity before build

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The relevant keyword to lookup is [TextAsset](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/TextAsset.html)

When you drag a text file into Unity, it gets treated as a type 'TextAsset'. Actually load the data either by linking it through a serialized variable or by using [Resources.Load](http://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/LoadingResourcesatRuntime.html) (just like any other asset: image, prefab, whatever)

Comment: Thank you, this answer has pointed me in the right directions